# Browse cells input in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table html with alternate input and checkbox.
My problems is when I want to browse my table with key tab.
When the focus is on checkbox the next tab is not the next cells but the next checkbox.
This is my code:

```
<form class="tabledit-form">

        <table id="table" class=" table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="head-num"><div><span>N°</span></div></th>
                    <th class="head-ba"><div><span>Ba</span></div></th>
                    <th class="head-num2"><div><span>N2°</span></div></th>
                    <th class="head-ba2"><div><span>Ba2</span></div></th>
                    <th class="head-num3"><div><span>N3°</span></div></th>
                    <th class="head-ba3"><div><span>Ba3</span></div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for i in nb_lines %}

                <tr class="line-{{forloop.counter}}">
                    <td id="lg-{{forloop.counter}}-col-1" tabindex="1"></td>
                    <td id="lg-{{forloop.counter}}-col-2" tabindex="2"><input type="checkbox" name="ba-1-lg-{{forloop.counter}}" /></td>
                    <td id="lg-{{forloop.counter}}-col-3" tabindex="3"></td>
                    <td id="lg-{{forloop.counter}}-col-4" tabindex="4"><input type="checkbox" name="ba-2-lg-{{forloop.counter}}" /></td>
                    <td id="lg-{{forloop.counter}}-col-5" tabindex="5"></td>
                    <td id="lg-{{forloop.counter}}-col-6" tabindex="6"><input type="checkbox" name="ba-3-lg-{{forloop.counter}}" /></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all try not to use tabindex>0 it is not recommended.

Read this for a better understading of **tabindex**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

See this example i have made:

```html
 <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cell 1</th>
          <th>Cell 2</th> 
          <th>Cell 3</th>
          <th>Cell 4</th>
          <th>Cell 5</th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td tabindex="0">Col</td>
          <td tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td tabindex="0">Col</td>
          <td tabindex="0"><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work when i have alternaly text and checkbox.

Comment: @smiss why not? see the edited  code snippet. Just add tabindex there where you want it to be focusable. Focus will be defined by the document's source order.

Comment: @smiss What do you want the cursor to focus on between checkboxes? There is no input element in the other cells, so you will not see the cursor. So what do you want the user to see?